# Is there any irrational algebraic number among the set?

Tags: nt.number-theory, transcendental-number-theory, infinite-sequences

Suppose $S$ is set of  numbers such that every number in it expands in decimal digits,every digit is 0 or 1,and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{C_{n}(0)}{n}=\frac{1}{2}$ where ${C_{n}(0)}$ and ${C_{n}(1)}$ are the counting numbers of 0,and 1 from first digit to n digit  respectively.

Now, is there any irrational algebraic number $x\in S$?. Obviously if there is one, there must be other irrational algebraic number

Comment: @Fan Zheng Thank you for your editing

Comment: I guess there is no irrational algebraic number $x \in S$

Comment: The probability such that  $x\notin S$ is 1

Comment: It is conjectured that every irrational algebraic number is normal, so even without your limit condition one expects the answer to be no.  Of course this normality conjecture is very hard -- your question is clearly easier, though not obviously (to me) within reach of current techniques.

Comment: I was just about to say what Daniel just said. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number#Properties_and_examples It seems your question would be an open problem (not really in the purview of MO).

Comment: @DanielLitt    I think it is not relating to normality since it's expansion in decimal has just 0 and 1.

Comment: @XL_at_China: The fact that you've required that every digit is $0$ or $1$ means that the number in question is not normal.

Comment: @DanielLitt yes, my fault, And I guess there is no irrational algebraic number which is normal, So this is about the guess that here is no irrational algebraic number $x\in s$. So the Irrational algebraic number is very strange, It is not like rational, and not like random number, They may be like some unnormal transcendental numbers.

Comment: XL, the conjecture is that *every* irrational algebraic *is* normal.

Comment: @ToddTrimble I know, so it is very strange, and my guess is contradict to the conjecture.

Comment: Again, as I said in my first comment, it's a notoriously unsolved problem whether the conjecture is true, and such problems are generally not considered on-topic for MO. See https://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic

Comment: @ToddTrimble I have just known the conjecture from other post on mathstack. Sorry, But possibly, we are lucky to find new way.

Comment: So there's already a discussion at Math.SE?  Started an hour ago? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2399799/is-any-irrational-algebraic-number-regular-number Cross-posting is very much frowned upon. Together with the fact that famous well-known problems are generally off-topic, this problem should be closed here.

Comment: @ToddTrimble no it is not this question